# Why is a (working) iTerm2 not staying in the Mac taskbar?

Tags: mac, terminal, taskbar, iterm2

I have [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) installed in `/Applications` on my MacBook Pro (running OSX Sierra), but if I right-click and select the option to pin it to the taskbar and log out and in again, there's some form of the [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) icon, but with a large white question mark imposed. Clicking it doesn't seem to do anything, and at very least doesn't open the expected windows.

Is there anything security-wise or other matter that I can address to have [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) whitelisted or registered as something I'm permitted to pin to the taskbar and start it by clicking its taskbar icon as I have with other applications?

Thanks,

Comment: Taskbar? You mean Dock, I presume.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing it?

Comment: I had a similar issue with a different program (Fantastical 2). To fix it I did the following: (1) Use Finder to move app from Applications to Desktop (2) Use Finder to move app from Desktop to Applications (3) launch app (4) right-click and keep in dock.  Maybe it'll work with iTerm2 as well?

Comment: What do you mean by 'right click and select option to pin it to the taskbar'?  I don't have an option for that. I just drag the app to the dock.